# Javascript timer counting down between two php dates

Tags: php, javascript, date

I am building a timer for a website that will count down between two php date()s.
The whole site uses php and there are a lot of time/date functions which rely on date_default_timezone_set() etc.

So, back tot he timmer...

I can get it working, well if I refresh my screen every second, the problem I currently have is the date/time is called via php, and obviously wont refresh when the javascript function does. What would be the best action? How could I get the:

```
dateNow = new Date(<?php date_default_timezone_set($row_currentauction['timezone_auc']); echo date("Y,m,d,H,i,s"); ?>);
```

part of my script to update?

Current code (uses mootools to flip image down like a airport display board, removed for example):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
   //<![CDATA[
    function retroClock(){

        dateFuture = new Date(<?php echo javadateEnd($row_currentauction['startdate_auc'], $row_currentauction['duration_auc'], $row_currentauction['extend_auc'],$row_currentauction['timezone_auc']); ?>);
        dateNow = new Date(<?php date_default_timezone_set($row_currentauction['timezone_auc']); echo date("Y,m,d,H,i,s"); ?>);

        difference = dateFuture.getTime() - dateNow.getTime(); //calculates difference between dates in ms

        days = 0; hours = 0; mins = 0; secs = 0;

        difference = Math.floor(difference/1000); //omit the "milliseconds"

        days = Math.floor(difference/86400);//days
        difference = difference%86400;

        hours = Math.floor(difference/3600);//hours
        difference = difference%3600;

        mins = Math.floor(difference/60);//minutes
        difference = difference%60;

        secs = Math.floor(difference);//seconds

        if( days < 2 ){document.getElementById('days').innerHTML="day";}else{document.getElementById('days').innerHTML="days";}
        if( hours < 2 ){document.getElementById('hours').innerHTML="hour";}else{document.getElementById('hours').innerHTML="hours";}
        if( mins < 2 ){document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML="minute";}else{document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML="minutes";}
        if( secs < 2 ){document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML="second";}else{document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML="seconds";}

        //change pads
        //rest of script...  
    }

    setInterval('retroClock()', 1000);

    //]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't put Php in a javascript script (Php is a server side technology whereas javascript is a client side technology) but you can retrieve your dates using [Ajax.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)

Comment: PHP can, however, output text that can be used as javascript.  That's often easier than relying on AJAX.

Comment: I had thought about Ajax, but was hoping for another way, don't fancy loading another file every second...